# How to connect a custom checkbox / input to LocalStorage in React using a Higher Order Component?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-functions

### Introduction

Yesterday I followed an advanced tutorial from Kent C. Dodds where he explained how to connect an input to [localstorage](/questions/tagged/localstorage) which then handles the setting of value, change of values etc and automatically sync with LocalStorage in [react](/questions/tagged/react).

At the first place this works pretty well for normal  components. However, for example the custom checkboxes which I have in my app do not work with the logics. I tried to alter the logics a bit but it seems that I didn't got far with it.

### The Problem

Currently my custom checkbox component does not connect / work with the [hoc](/questions/tagged/hoc) **LocalStorageFormControl**.

### Project info

> I have made a CodeSandbox for you to play around with: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-curie-8sj1x

The project is using standard bootstrap with scss stylings. The CustomCheckbox consists of two elements: the main div and the actual input itself. Currently the matching value in state will trigger className change in one of the elements to allow custom styling.

For any further questions please comment below. Thanks in advance for all the help.

### Resources

[Kent C. Dodds - Tutorial resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=bfRjtGfYETk)

[CodeSandBox Project](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-curie-8sj1x)

Comment: What does "do not work well" specifically mean?

Comment: @po.pe I am sorry for not being clear. It does not work as it does not handle setting the value and changing the states correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems were:

1. The `LocalStorageFormControl` component didn't update the state when
   it gets the initial value from localStorage.
2. The `input` didn't update the state onChange as it didn't have `onChange`
   handler.
3. The `CustomCheckboxGroup` component didn't have a `name` prop which is used
   as a part of the `key` in the `localStorage`

The solution is as following:

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// Bootstrap
import { Row, Col, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import CustomCheckboxGroup from "./CustomCheckboxGroup";

// Function that calls all functions in order to allow the user to provide their own onChange, value etc
const callAll = (...fns) => (...args) => fns.forEach(fn => fn && fn(...args));

// Connect any <input /> to LocalStorage and let it manage value / onChange
function LocalStorageFormControl({
  children,
  formControl = React.Children.only(children),
  lsKey = `lsfc:${formControl.props.name}`,
  updateInitialState
}) {
  const [hasChanged, setHasChanged] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    return (
      window.localStorage.getItem(lsKey) || formControl.props.defaultValue || ""
    );
  });

  // Let the user control the value if needed
  if (
    formControl.props.value !== undefined &&
    formControl.props.value !== value
  ) {
    setValue(formControl.props.value);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasChanged) {
      if (value) {
        window.localStorage.setItem(lsKey, value);
      } else {
        window.localStorage.removeItem(lsKey);
      }
    } else {
      if (value) {
        // if hasChanged is false and there is value that means there was a value in localStorage
        setHasChanged(true);
        // update the state
        updateInitialState(value);
      }
    }
  }, [value, lsKey, hasChanged, updateInitialState]);

  return React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(children), {
    onChange: callAll(formControl.props.onChange, e => {
      setHasChanged(true);
      setValue(e.target.value);
    }),
    value,
    defaultValue: undefined
  });
}

const checkboxes = [
  {
    label: "Dhr",
    name: "aanhef-dhr",
    stateName: "salutation",
    value: "De heer"
  },
  {
    label: "Mevr",
    name: "aanhef-mevr",
    stateName: "salutation",
    value: "Mevrouw"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Handling submission of the form");
  }

  function onChange(e, stateName) {
    e.persist();
    setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [stateName]: e.target.value }));
  }

  // Log the state to the console
  console.log(state);

  return (
    <Row>
      <Col xs={12}>
        <Form
          id="appointment-form"
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          noValidate
          style={{ marginBottom: 75 }}
        >
          <LocalStorageFormControl
            updateInitialState={value => {
              setState({ ...state, "test-textfield": value });
            }}
          >
            {/* Add onChange handler to update the state with input value*/}
            <input
              type="text"
              name="test-textfield"
              onChange={e => {
                setState({ ...state, "test-textfield": e.target.value });
              }}
            />
          </LocalStorageFormControl>
          <LocalStorageFormControl
            updateInitialState={value => {
              setState({ ...state, salutation: value });
            }}
          >
            <CustomCheckboxGroup
              checkboxes={checkboxes}
              key="salutation"
              label="Salutation"
              name="salutation"
              onChange={(e, stateName) => onChange(e, stateName)}
              required={true}
              value={state.salutation}
            />
          </LocalStorageFormControl>
        </Form>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
}
```

CustomCheckboxGroup.js

```js
import React from "react";

// Bootstrap
import { Form, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

export default ({ onChange, value, name, label, className, checkboxes }) => (
  <Row>
    <Col xs={12}>
      <Form.Label>{label}</Form.Label>
    </Col>

    <Col>
      <Form.Group className="d-flex flex-direction-column">
        {checkboxes.map((checkbox, key) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={key}
              className={
                checkbox.value === value
                  ? "appointment_checkbox active mr-2 custom-control custom-checkbox"
                  : "appointment_checkbox mr-2 custom-control custom-checkbox"
              }
            >
              <input
                name={name}
                type="checkbox"
                value={checkbox.value}
                onChange={e => onChange(e, checkbox.stateName)}
                checked={value === checkbox.value}
                id={"checkbox-" + checkbox.name}
                className="custom-control-input"
              />
              <label
                className="custom-control-label"
                htmlFor={"checkbox-" + checkbox.name}
              >
                {checkbox.label}
              </label>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </Form.Group>
    </Col>
  </Row>
);
```

I have some advice about your code:

1. Use radio buttons instead of checkboxes if you allow the user to choose one option only. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio
2. You can persist the whole state object if you would like to by replacing this:

   ```
   const [state, setState] = useState({});
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   // Get the saved state in local storage if it exists or use an empty object
   // You must use JSON.parse to convert the string back to a javascript object
   const initialState = localStorage.getItem("form-state")
     ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("form-state"))
     : {};
   // Initialize the state with initialState
   const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

   // Whenever the state changes save it to local storage
   // Notice that local storage accepts only strings so you have to use JSON.stringify
   useEffect(() => {
     localStorage.setItem("form-state", JSON.stringify(state));
   }, [state]);
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the solution you're providing. The input field has always been working. The custom checkbox is not working with localstorage at the moment. When you wrap the <CustomCheckboxGroup /> around with <LocalStorageFormControl /> and refresh the page, the state and localstorage is not working with the custom checkbox. :-)

Comment: I updated the answer. I don't know why you are using this pattern. Is there a specific use case?. In the real world, you would want to save and get the whole state not every single field. You can do that as i showed you in the example and if you are using a form library like `react-final-form` or `formik` you can do the same by saving the whole state to `localStorage` whenever one of the field values change and in case of refreshing the page you can get the state in initial render and use it as the form `initialValues` prop. I hope that answered your question.

Comment: I think you're totally right about the fact that I should store the form state as a whole. Though it was sort of an experiment and based on a talk from Kent c. Dodds. The reason why i choose to do this, was because some fields shouldn't be stored in the localstorage so I made an HOC out of it. Thanks for your answer and help!

Comment: The only thing that bothers me in the solution is that now the name property is on the CustomCheckboxgroup which isn't the native element but just a wrapper around two input fields of type checkbox. Is there anything we can do about that part?

Comment: `LocalStorageFormControl` uses its children `name` prop as a part of the key as the default value `lsKey = `lsfc:${formControl.props.name}``

If you want to override instead of passing name you can pass a `lsKey` prop.

Comment: I understand that it uses the childrens name property. However normally a name property should be on an input field. Since name is a native property on the native <input />, right?